# Limitar o número de linhas de consultas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho a seguinte Query

```
SELECT estado, num_ocorrencia
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC
```

Ela me retorna todos os estados com os números de ocorrências mais relevantes que eu tenho na tabela, eu gostaria de reduzir a consulta apenas as **5 primeiras linhas** que ela me retorna. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [SELECT, TOP e ROWNUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Comment: Adicione a cláusula `LIMIT 5`

Comment: @MatheusReis pensando em performance em grande escala de dados, você sabe me dizer qual é a melhor forma de fazer este retorno?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para limitar a quantidade de linhas, você pode user as cláusulas `LIMIT`,`TOP` e `ROWNUM`. Ex:

```
SELECT estado, num_ocorrencia
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
LIMIT 5
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC
```

Ou

```
SELECT estado, num_ocorrencia
TOP 5
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC;
```

Ou

```
SELECT estado, num_ocorrencia
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
AND ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC
```

## Referência

- [SQL LIMIT, TOP AND ROWNUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

## Editado

Conforme informado nas demais respostas, das 3 cláusulas citadas, o `PostgreSQL` suporta apenas a `LIMIT`.

Existe também a possibilidade de utilizar o [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-fetch.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM  bra_ocorrencias
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia  DESC
FETCH 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Pensando em performance e supondo isso num cenário de grande volume de dados, qual é a melhor maneira de fazer este retorno?

Comment: Entre o `TOP` e o `ROWNUMBER`, o Top é consideravelmente mais eficiente. Referência: [TOP vs ROWNUMBER](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4938/sql-server-performance-comparison-of-top-vs-rownumber/)

Comment: O `PostgreSQL` não possui `TOP` e nem `ROWNUM`!

Comment: Editado, @Lacobus.

Answer (score 3):

A cláusula TOP da linguagem SQL é utilizada para limitar o número de registros retornados por uma consulta

```
SELECT TOP 5  num_ocorrencia, estado
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC;
```

Comment: O `PostgreSQL` não possui `TOP`!

Comment: mas a pergunta é pra #SQL

Comment: Vou colocar o equivalente na outra resposta

Answer (score 2):

Use o `LIMIT`

```
SELECT estado, num_ocorrencia
FROM bra_ocorrencias
WHERE nome like 'João'
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC
LIMIT num_limit
```

Leia mais [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)!

Answer (score 2):

Para isso (postgresql) você pode usar o limit

```
select *
from bra_ocorrencias
order by num_ocorrencia desc
limit 5
```

Se o desempenho é importante procure por um índice na pontuação.
você também pode usar o padrão ( SQL: 2008 )fetch first

```
select *
from bra_ocorrencias
order by num_ocorrencia  desc
fetch first 5 rows only
```

Comment: Ao invés de postar outra resposta, você deveria ter editado a sua e acrescentado as informações

Comment: uma resposta trata para SQL e outra pra Postgrest